# Override parent's inner interface?

Tags: java, android

I have two classes which are very similar except for a few methods. For this reason I want to have all methods in one class (Parent) and then extend Parent from Child overriding a few of it's methods and interfaces. For what I've seen declaring a method in the child directly overrides the same method from the parent, however I haven't been able to override the parent interfaces. This is what I'm trying:

Parent class:

```
public class ContactList extends ListFragment implements SwipeListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    //...

    public interface ContactsQuery {
        final static int QUERY_ID = 1;
        final static Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        final static String SELECTION = Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1" + " AND " + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1" + " AND " + (Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME) + "<>''";

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        final static String SORT_ORDER = Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        final static String[] PROJECTION = {
                Contacts._ID,
                Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                SORT_ORDER,
        };

        // The query column numbers which map to each value in the projection
        final static int ID = 0;
        final static int LOOKUP_KEY = 1;
        final static int DISPLAY_NAME = 2;
        final static int SORT_KEY = 3;
    }
```

Child class:

```
public class ContactListFavs extends ContactList {
    public interface ContactsQuery {
        final static int QUERY_ID = 1;
        final static Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        final static String SELECTION = Contacts.STARRED + " AND " + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1" + " AND " + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1" + " AND " + (Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME) + "<>''";

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        final static String SORT_ORDER = Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        final static String[] PROJECTION = {
                Contacts._ID,
                Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, Utils.hasHoneycomb() ? Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                SORT_ORDER,
        };

        // The query column numbers which map to each value in the projection
        final static int ID = 0;
        final static int LOOKUP_KEY = 1;
        final static int DISPLAY_NAME = 2;
        final static int SORT_KEY = 3;
    }
}
```

However I cannot figure out how to do it. When instantiating a Child class it uses the interface from it's parent. How can I override it with the child's method?

Comment: Should work. How are you initializing the child object?

Comment: Looks good to me. Make sure to create an object of type `Child`.

Comment: I've actually been able to override the Parent's methods however I'm struggling to override an interface. I'm initializing the child from my MainActivity which adds it to a viewpager.

Comment: you have changed the code a lot after the first comment. Looks like you want to override an inner private interface in subclass which is not possible

Comment: I hadn't noticed there was an interface when I asked the question. I can change the interface to public or protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Do it Like this...

```
class Parent
    {
        interface myP{
            public int good();
            public int good2();
            public int good3();
        }

    }

class Child extends Parent
    {
      interface myC extends Parent.myP{
            public int good();
            public int NOTgood();
        }
    }
```

What will happen here is if you `extend` `Child` and `implement` `Child.myC` you have to implement all methods which are in this case..

Child Interface (myC) Methods:

```
public int good();
public int NOTgood();
```

Parent Interface (myP) Method:

```
public int good();
public int good2();
public int good3();
```

But you need to keep access modifier interfaces public ,Default or protected but **not private**

Here in both interfaces there is a common method `good()`.

Comment: my problem with this is that the parent's methods will still call myP interface instead of myC.

Comment: Here myC extends myP so if you implement myC automatically myP is also implemented so you have to implement methods which are not just in myC but also in myP.So ultimately by extending child you can get access to parents interface.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of class `Parent` extending try to use and implement interface for both classes (super and subclass). The version is a bit more verbose but although it's more maintainable and clear for code reuse and modification:

```
public interface iCalculate 
{
    public int calculate();
}

public class Parent implements iCalculate
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int res = calculate();
    }

    public int calculate()
    {
        return 1 + 1;
    }
}

public class Child implements iCalculate
{
    public int calculate()
    {
        return 2 + 2;
    }
}
```

If you are on Java 8 you could use [default methods in interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) implementation to achieve traditional inheritance functionality. This time (in interface default methods case) you don't need to implement a method when default behavior is appropriate for you.